# General term of the math succession

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What is the general term of the following succession?

$1, 6, 16, 37, 63, 113, 163, 248, 339, 469, 591, 801, 971, 1221, 1481, 1822, 2112...$

I get stuck on this exercise.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: see here https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C6%2C16%2C37%2C63%2C113%2C&language=english&go=Search

Comment: I know that is the sum of all the divisors. For example,  $a(6) = 1^2 + (1^2 + 2^2) + (1^2+3^2) + (1^2+2^2+4^2) + (1^2+5^2) + (1^2+2^2+3^2+6^2)$  But, I don't know to put in a general formula.

Comment: I have seen the oeis.org , but I doesn't understand the formulas

Comment: You'd better put this into your post so that others can see your attempts (and avoid closure of question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a(k)=\sum_{n=1}^k\sum_{d\mid n}d^2$$

Comment: What means $d|n$?

Comment: The symbol $\mid$ means 'divide'. So $d\mid n$ is the set of the divisors of $n$, including $1$ and itself.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand the formuka

Comment: You are correct in giving the example that $$a(6) = (1^2) + (1^2 + 2^2) + (1^2+3^2) + (1^2+2^2+4^2) + (1^2+5^2) + (1^2+2^2+3^2+6^2)$$ Now notice that each term in brackets is the sum of the squares of the divisors of the number. So we have $$1^2=\sum_{d\mid1}d^2\\(1^2+2^2)=\sum_{d\mid2}d^2$$ and so on. Use the summation symbol to sum each of these summations to get the form shown above.

Comment: Actually, I need to find the term $10^{17}$ and $12^{24}$  in Maxima, but I don't know to put the formula have you said in this language.

Comment: Do: `sum(divsum(n, 2), n, 1, 10^17)`. If you have found this answer useful please accept it (tick).

Comment: It doesn't efficient. It doesn't calculate

Comment: Well I can't do much to help since I don't have Maxima. Anyway this is not the point of your question. You may wish to ask this on Stack Overflow though.